# restframework-jwt how can I handle payload?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I used Django restframework to implement api server.

Also I used djangorestframework-jwt for token authentication.

[urls.py]

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework_jwt.views import refresh_jwt_token

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('refresh-token/', refresh_jwt_token),
]
```

Everything works fine. But I want to know that How can I extract payload from token?

For example, There is article table.

[/article/serializers.py]

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

[models.py]

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

[views.py]

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from . import models, serializers

class Article(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        all_article = models.Article.objects.all()
        serializer = serializers.ArticleSerializer(all_article, many=True)

        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

In this case, I want to return correct response only payload['userid'] == article's userid.

How can I extract username from jwt token?

Previous, I just use jwt not djangorestframework-jwt, So just decode request data and use it.

But now I use djangorestframework-jwt, I confused How can I do it.

Is there any solution about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue after checking the library's documentation here

https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/

I needed to Override all the functions to return custom response as required in my application.

Also any additional settings we need to specify in JWT_AUTH in settings.py of my application.

i.e.

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'myapp.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',
}
```

And needed to define `jwt_response_payload_handler` function in a util folder in my app to override the default function.